# Building n by n grid with specifics

Tags: python, for-loop

This is a homework problem, just putting it out there.

I'm trying to build an n by n grid where the digit in the rth row and the cth column should be the last digit of r * c (I don't understand exactly what this is asking either, so I'm also stuck there). n is user-supplied.

My main problem is that I cannot make the grid work how I want it.

This is my code so far:

```
# get dimension of the digit box
reply = input( "Enter integer: " )
n = int( reply )

# print an n-by-n grid one row at a time.
for r in range(0, n):
    # handle printing of the row r entries for the digit box
    print(r, end=" ")
    print()
    for c in range(0, n):
        cell = (r * c) % 10
        print(c, end=" ")
    print()
```

And this is what it returns (n = 4 in this run):

```
Enter integer: 4
0 
0 1 2 3 
1 
0 1 2 3 
2 
0 1 2 3 
3 
0 1 2 3
```

I don't understand why this is what it returns, or what to do to make it do what I want. I know that if I want to get the digit it's asking for I have to use the `%` operator, but I don't quite know how to use it or where, so I hope I did it right so far.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: the grid is supposed to look like this:

```
Enter integer: 4

0 0 0 0 

0 1 2 3 

0 2 4 6 

0 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 3):

You are printing c instead of cell, and also printing r. This is what your code *should* look like:

```py
# get dimension of the digit box
reply = input("Enter integer: ")
n = int(reply)

# print an n-by-n grid one row at a time.
for r in range(0, n):
    # handle printing of the row r entries for the digit box
    # print(r, end=" ") REMOVE THIS
    print()
    for c in range(0, n):
        cell = (r * c) % 10
    #   print(c, end=" ") REMOVE THIS
        print(cell, " ")
    print()
```